# Кастомайзер в Wordpress выдает в консоли 403

Tags: wordpress, настройки

В WordPress теме evolve+ есть настройки в кастомайзере с использованием Kirki плагина, когда выбираешь настройку, например изменение цвета темы то ничего не меняется, а консоли появляется 403 ошибка. Плагины все отключала, все равно не помогает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить эти ошибки?
[image: ошибки]

Comment: Такое может происходить из-за того, что у пользователя недостаточно прав (не администратор).

Comment: Там пользователь администратор http://prntscr.com/ny1vll

Comment: Без открытого кастомайзера есть только 1 ошибка http://prntscr.com/ny1we1